# how can i see output in terminal for a process generated by fork()

Tags: c, network-programming

I wrote code for concurrent server. I want to see output in terminal for child server socket that is generated by `fork()` call. Client is communicating with child server socket and i want to see data written by client on server. So how can i see it in terminal?

my server code:

```
while(1)
     {
      clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
      connfd=accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr,&clilen);
      printf("connection accepted\n");
       if((childpid=fork())==0)
          {
            close(sockfd);
            printf("child process\n");
            str_echo(connfd);
           // str_echo(connfd);
            exit(0);
          }
     printf("connection established\n");
```

str_echo()

```
void str_echo(int sockfd)
    {
      char buff[20];
      ssize_t n;
      while(1)
          {
           if((n=read(sockfd,buff,20))>=0)
              write(sockfd,buff,20);
           else
              write(sockfd,"blank",20);
           //else
             printf("%s",buff);
             // write(sockfd,buff,20);
              //return;
           //else
             // writen(sockfd,buff,n);
           }
     }
```

but i am not getting output for above `printf("%s",buff);` in `str_echo()` in terminal

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `read()` hasn't returned yet? You could try putting a `print` at the beginning of `str_echo` and see if you see that.

Comment: Is the parent process' stdout redirected? Can you reproduce the problem in code that does nothing bit fork, printf, exit, and wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually a forked() process shares its parents file descriptors, in particular it should have the same `stdout`. So I think that you should be able to see the output without doing any special setup.

Comment: no i tried this code for server:
if((childpid=fork())==0)
          {
            close(sockfd);
            str_echo(connfd);

and
while(1)
          {
           if((n=read(sockfd,buff,20))>=0)
              write(sockfd,buff,20);
           else
              write(sockfd,"blank",20);
           //else
             printf("%s",buff);

but i am not getting output in terminal for printf("%s",buff)

Comment: @subh. sing Sorry if this sounds like a silly question but isn't that because it's commented out? Also you could put the code in the question so it would be easier to see.

Comment: @cnicutar oh that's a good point. @subh. sing Sometimes output doesn't get `flushed()` until a newline happens. You could add `\n` or call `fflush()` explicitly.